# QGIS: Exporting as KML with split vector layer retains all attribute and filepath information visible in Google Earth

Tags: qgis, export, kml, google-earth, splitting

I am trying to export features to a KML file so field technicians can view the data via Google Earth since not everyone can operate QGIS and its a bit more user friendly when they just need to be able to see the features and zoom in/out and pan around the area.

However when I export the data via split vector layer, I cannot choose which attributes to include and which to exclude like I can when using "Save As...", but using split vector layer is much quicker since we only want field technicians from each city to have access to only their city's data. So I split the layer using the unique field of "Program". However I do not want to include all the attributes, just a few.

Also, when I open the KML file in Google Earth, the stupid popup that occurs when I click on a feature shows the filepath before the attribute field name.

Is there a way to remove the filepath from the field name when exporting as a KML file, whether beforehand in QGIS or afterwards in Google Earth?

[image]

Comment: If you export your layer with [mmqgis](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/), you can use “Description Separator: Custom HTML” where you can set the field name manually.